# Awk AND operator

Tags: awk

A basic question about AND logical operator. I'm trying to extract some fields in my data file niveles.csv based on values of columns 1 and 2. I'd like to write an awk sentence saying "when field1=date and field2=area then print fields 3 to 5".

My data file looks like

```
01-08-12;1;0;0;0
01-08-12;2;1;1;1
01-08-12;3;0;0;1
................
```

awk sentence inside a bash script is

```
date=01-08-2012
area=8
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}  $1 ~ /'$date'/ && $2 ~ /'$area'/ { print $1 " " $2 " "  $3 " " $4 " " $5 }' niveles-rams.cs
```

But this just gives fields for the three cases where area number has an 8 inside (8,18 and 28) while I just want only area 8 data

```
01-08-2012 8 0 0 0
01-08-2012 18 2 2 1
01-08-2012 28 2 1 0
```

Thanks in advance for your attention, sure it is a simple question for experienced users.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not tested:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}  $1 ~ /'$date'/ && $2 == '$area'{......}'
```

$2 ~ /8/  -> this means if 2nd field contains 8

$2 == 8  -> this means if 2nd field is equal to 8

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the difference between ~ and ==

Comment: No. Do NOT do that! See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to access the value of shell variables form an awk script and see @Barmar's answer here.

Comment: @EdMorton : I agree that this is not the right way to access shell variables...the solution is provided to make the OP's solution work...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to give him a solution that doesn't fail cryptically some day though?

Answer (score 14):

<sub>Since this question is getting a lot of attention because of its title, let me post a more generic answer covering how to use the `AND` operator in `awk`.</sub>

Say you have a file `myfile`:

```
a 1 2 3
b 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

If you are looking for a way to do some multiple checks using the `AND` operator, you need to use `&&` like this:

```
awk '$2 < 10 && $3 > 2' myfile
```

Which would return:

```
b 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

---

In general, you can use as many conditions as you want, taking into consideration that

```
AND --> &&
OR  --> ||
```

So you can combine multiple logical expressions like for example:

```
awk '($2 < 10 || $3 > 2) && ($2 > 10 || $3 < 2)' myfile
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 11):

Use awk's `-v` option to create awk variables containing the shell variables.

```
awk -v date="$date" -v area="$area" '$1 == date && $2 == area { ... }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok, I gave it a little test:

```
date="01-08-12"
area=8
awk -F\; '$1 == "'$date'" && $2 == '$area' { print $3 " " $4 " " $5 }' niveles-rams.csv
```

If you want the date and area fields in there then the awk statement looks like this:

```
awk -F\; '$1 == "'$date'" && $2 == '$area' { print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 }' niveles-rams.csv
```

Comment: No. Do NOT do that! See cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to access the value of shell variables form an awk script and see @Barmar's answer here.

Comment: you could use `-awk -F\; -vOFS=' ' '$1 == "'$date'" && $2 == '$area' { print $3, $4, $5 }' niveles-rams.csv` no comment on the rest of this, I'm no awk expert, I just noticed the cool OFS var, instead of adding all the empty spaces in quotes